# how can i use a ngIf cycle inside a ngFor cycle?

Tags: html, angular

I've to verify if my array is empty or not and if it's empty i've to pass a special message,
That's what i tried:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" ngFor let-car [ngForOf]="cars">
                <span *ngIf="cars.lenght==0">
                    <div style="float: left; width: auto;"> Ancora nessuna prenotazione per questo veicolo </div>
                </span>
                <span>
                    <div style="float: left; width: 153px;"> {{car.driver}} </div>
                    <div style="float: left; width: 153px;"> {{car.date1 | momentFormat:'DD/MM/YYYY'}} </div>
                    <div style="float: left; width: 153px;"> {{car.date2 | momentFormat:'DD/MM/YYYY'}} </div>
                    <div style="float: left; width: 153px;"> {{car.description}} </div>
                </span>
            </ng-template>
```

It doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check length of your array before rendering them in `ngFor` and create a fallback `ng-template` to show that there is no items:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="cars && cars.length > 0; else noCars"> 
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" ngFor let-car [ngForOf]="cars">
        <div style="float: left; width: 153px;"> {{car.driver}} </div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 153px;"> {{car.date1 | momentFormat:'DD/MM/YYYY'}} </div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 153px;"> {{car.date2 | momentFormat:'DD/MM/YYYY'}} </div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 153px;"> {{car.description}} </div>            
    </ng-template>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #noCars>
    <div style="float: left; width: auto;"> 
        Ancora nessuna prenotazione per questo veicolo 
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```html
<div *ngIf="!cars.length; else list">
  No cars
</div>
<ng-template #list>
  <div *ngFor="let car of cars">
    {{car}}
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Technically you don't need to do anything though, `ngIf` will always be false if there is any car and `ngFor` will show 0 items if there are none, so they are mutually exclusive. This will also work:

```html
<div *ngIf="!cars.length">
  No cars
</div>
<div *ngFor="let car of cars">
  {{car}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code must work:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let car of cars;">
    <span *ngIf="cars.lenght==0">
                    <div style="float: left; width: auto;"> Ancora nessuna prenotazione per questo veicolo </div>
                </span>
                <span>
                    <div style="float: left; width: 153px;"> {{car.driver}} </div>
                    <div style="float: left; width: 153px;"> {{car.date1 | momentFormat:'DD/MM/YYYY'}} </div>
                    <div style="float: left; width: 153px;"> {{car.date2 | momentFormat:'DD/MM/YYYY'}} </div>
                    <div style="float: left; width: 153px;"> {{car.description}} </div>
                </span>
  </ng-container>
```